# Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var toplamgun = 0;
var toplampazar = 0;
for (var yıl = 1900; ++yıl < 2001;){
    for(var ay= 0; ++ay<13;){
        if (ay == 2){

        }
        else{
            var eklenecekgun = AydakiGunler[ay] // error is here
            toplamgun += eklenecekgun
            yenigunindex = toplamgun % 7;
            if(yenigunindex == 6){
                toplampazar += 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
console.log(toplampazar);
var AydakiGunler = [0,31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
```

cant get an item from an array by index

here is the error 
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

im trying to https://projecteuler.net/problem=19

Comment: well, `AydakiGunler` isn't defined until after the code is run - var declarations are hoisted, but not the value

Comment: i hate js, yes it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `AydakiGunler` *before* trying to access it. Your code would then look like this:

```js
var AydakiGunler = [0,31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

var toplamgun = 0;
var toplampazar = 0;
for (var yıl = 1900; ++yıl < 2001;){
    for(var ay= 0; ++ay<13;){
        if (ay == 2){

        }
        else{
            var eklenecekgun = AydakiGunler[ay] // error is here
            toplamgun += eklenecekgun
            yenigunindex = toplamgun % 7;
            if(yenigunindex == 6){
                toplampazar += 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
console.log(toplampazar);
```

I'm afraid I don't speak Turkish, so I can't help you any further in what you're trying to do, but either way I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Define `AydakiGunler` before your for loop.

`var` variables are hoisted and declared at the top your file but they're undefined before its initialization.

```
 var toplamgun = 0;
    var toplampazar = 0;
    var AydakiGunler = [0,31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
    for (var yıl = 1900; ++yıl < 2001;){
        for(var ay= 0; ++ay<13;){
            if (ay == 2){

            }
            else{
                var eklenecekgun = AydakiGunler[ay] // error is here
                toplamgun += eklenecekgun
                yenigunindex = toplamgun % 7;
                if(yenigunindex == 6){
                    toplampazar += 1;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    console.log(toplampazar);
```